# Get unique values in matrix with Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, unique-values

I'm looking for fastest way to get unique values in matrix with Matlab! I have a matrix like this:

```
1       2
1       2
1       3
1       5
1       23
2       1
3       1
3       2
3       2
3       2
4       17
4       3
4       17
```

and need to get something like this:

```
1       2
1       3
1       5
1       23
2       1
3       1
3       2
4       3
4       17
```

Actually I need unique values by combination of columns in each row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at matlabs `unique()` function with the argument 'rows'.

```
C = unique(A,'rows')
```

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html